# XMLUnit ignore Order of Elements

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit

I compare two xml files with each other with the help of XMLUnit 
now if i use this code to compare

```
@Test
public void testForEquality() throws Exception {
 String xml1 = "<table = "01"><uid></uid></table><table = "02"><uid></uid></table>";
 String xml2 = "<table = "02"><uid></uid></table><table = "01"><uid></uid></table>";
 assertXMLEqual(myControlXML, myTestXML);
 Diff diff = new Diff(myControlXML, myTestXML);
 assertTrue(diff.similar());
}
```

now it gives me out: Expected attribute value '02' but was '01'
but i don't want a difference i want the table id to be unique and only check 
what the Main-Element in this case:table -> contains if the same table id is seen in the other file.

i allready lookt through simmilar questions but they did not helped me out.

Comment: are you sure that's your XML? because that's not valid XML. You're missing an attribute name in the table node.

Comment: either way, if you only want to compare the attribute values of the table nodes, use XPath to isolate them and compare. XMLUnit supports that via XMLAssert.assertXpathsEqual

Comment: @Renan nope it's not my XML just used it as explanatory purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell XMLUnit which rules to apply to identify the table elements it should match with each other.  You do so by configuring an `ElementQualifier` - in your case you will want to use the built-in `ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier` passing the identifying attribute's name as constructor argument.